# Issue with Cursor When Trying to Query an SQLite Database

Tags: android-sqlite

I am pretty new to SQLite and have been trying to figure this out for a few days by searching this site and googling.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

For some reason when I am trying to populate items from my database into a ListView, I am getting the error below:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(boolean,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I am not sure why as I am pretty sure I am instantiating the Cursor.  Again, I am new at this.  Please see my DBAdapter class and MainActivity class below.  Thank you!!

> public class DBAdapter {

```
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE = "exercise";
public static final String KEY_BODYPART = "bodypart";
public static final String KEY_EQUIP = "equip";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_BODYPART, KEY_EQUIP};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_EXERCISE = 1;
public static final int COL_BODYPART = 2;
public static final int COL_EQUIP = 3;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbExercises";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "exerciseList";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_EXERCISE + " VARCHAR, "
        + KEY_BODYPART + " VARCHAR, "
        + KEY_EQUIP + " VARCHAR"
        + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String exercise, String bodypart, String equip) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exercise);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODYPART, bodypart);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EQUIP, equip);

    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_EXERCISE, task);
    newValues.put(KEY_BODYPART, date);
    newValues.put(KEY_EQUIP, date);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

> public class Switchercise extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DBAdapter myDb;
Cursor cursor;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.switchercise);

    openDB();
    populateListeView();
    closeDB();


    }



//method to open database
public void openDB(){
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
}



//method to close database
public void closeDB(){
    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.close();
}



//method to put all records in db into the listview
public void populateListeView(){


    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);

    cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_EXERCISE, DBAdapter.KEY_BODYPART, DBAdapter.KEY_EQUIP};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.tvExercise, R.id.tvBodyPart, R.id.tvEquip};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs);
    ListView mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewExercises);
    mylist.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);



}




}
```

As requested....

> 04-16 13:53:34.531 19027-19027/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
>   04-16 13:53:34.531 19027-19027/? E/Zygote: v2
>   04-16 13:53:34.531 19027-19027/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   04-16 13:53:34.531 19027-19027/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   04-16 13:53:36.361 19027-19027/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@245fe182
>   04-16 13:53:36.361 19027-19027/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@2014d093
>   04-16 13:53:36.361 19027-19027/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@2014d093
>   04-16 13:53:36.391 19027-19027/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed, PID: 19027
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed/com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed.Switchercise}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                          at com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed.DBAdapter.getAllRows(DBAdapter.java:94)
>                                                          at com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed.Switchercise.populateListeView(Switchercise.java:56)
>                                                          at com.sillyfidgetapps.jesscastro.workmeouttabbed.Switchercise.onCreate(Switchercise.java:26)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you try: `Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name", null); if(c!=null){ c.moveToFirst(); } return c;`

Comment: Dont know if Ur still having this problem, but the nullpointer seems to be where you call `getAllRows` so i think you should try the option i gave Adove.